# Cannot open sqlite command line interface

Tags: sqlite, flask, cmd

I used the following on the cmd to try and open the sqlite command line interface, but somehow it is not recognised.

I can see the sqlite db has been created, so cannot see what I am doing wrong:

```
(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>sqlite
'sqlite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>
```

I've also tried typing at the prompt: >>sqlite3

Still, the same error.

Comment: Do you actually have sqlite3 installed?

Comment: What does `dir /S \sqlite3.*` return when executed on the drive the command is supposed to be?

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## download `slqlit3`

to download `slqlit3` go to this url: https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

since your are working on `windows` platform, under **Precompiled Binaries for Windows** section download `sqlite-tools-win64-x64-3320300.zip` or `sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3320300.zip` if your are like me working on the very OLD `windows 7 32bit` architecture

you have to know `sqlite3` is a standalone and executable file meaning `sqlite3` don't require to be installed like other programs:

> A **bundle of command-line tools** for managing SQLite database files, including the command-line shell program, the sqldiff.exe program, and the sqlite3_analyzer.exe program.

unzip the downloaded file the under `C:\` for e.g. and rename the folder to `C:\sqlite3` to make things simple.

now, if you open : `C:\sqlite3`, you'll find 3 executable files:

```
C:\sqlite3
  sqldiff.exe
  **sqlite3.exe**
  sqlite3_analyzer.exe
```

## add an `Environment Variable`

- open `System Properties` (see this [post](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/6-ways-to-open-computer-or-system-properties-in-windows-10.html))
- go to `Advanced` tab under `System Properties` and click `Environment Variables`
- Under `System Variables` create those variables:

  - `PYTHON_HOME` = `C:\Python37` (it depends where you already installed python  and which version if you have multiple installations)
  - `SQLITE_HOME` = `C:\sqlite3`
- go to `User variables` and add/append variables to `PATH` like so:

  - `PATH` = `[..];%PYTHON_HOME%;%PYTHON_HOME%\Scripts;`

open new console and check your current active python:

```
python --version
```

and then you can use `sqlite3` command not `sqlite` (check the `C:\sqlite3` installation folder):

```
(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>sqlite
'sqlite' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>sqlite3 -version
3.15.2 2016-11-28 19:13:37 bbd85d235f7037c6a033a9690534391ffeacecc8
```

now you can open the `sqlite` database file (e.g: `data-dev.sqlite3` under `/myflaskproject` ) like

```
(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>sqlite3 data-dev.sqlite3
SQLite version 3.15.2 2016-11-28 19:13:37
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite>
```

some quick useful `sqlite` commands

```
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file

---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------

0    main             E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject\data-dev.sqlite3

sqlite> .tables
user
sqlite> .exit (to exit)
```

for more about `sqlite` have look at this site [sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/)

Comment: I haven't downloaded it - but shouldn't it be packaged with flask. The tutorial followed doesn't explcitly download it...

Comment: `Flask` is un-opinionated micro-framework that means `Flask` won’t make decisions for you, such as what database to use nor chipping an external executable (sqlite3.exe) and not even support for any database (builtin classes, libs) if you want, you can install an extension that extends `Flask` capabilities like the famous  `Flask-SALAlchemy`

Comment: if my answer was useful for you consider accepting it.

Comment: I need to verify it works....thank you. Any thoughts on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579373/opening-python-file-with-idle-version-3-7-and-the-venv-has-3-8-installed-no

Comment: (env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>pip install sqlite3
Collecting sqlite3
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>

Comment: I can't follow your answer at all. You start by saying - on windows add an Environment variable!? Where is the sqlite3 path. Too much assumed, and I can't follow it I'm afraid. I tried pip install sqlite3 in the venv and it resulted in the above ERROR.

Comment: `(env) E:\Python installation\myproject\myflaskproject>pip install sqlite3` you are doing things the wrong way. i'll update my answer in short, it's easy than you think